# Can I delay a systemd script from running at boot?

Tags: boot, systemd

I have two `systemd` scripts that I want to run on boot up.

1. The first systemd script starts OpenVPN, which then executes a shell script that writes the IP of the connection to the file `vpn.env`.
2. The second systemd script starts Transmission and should bind to the IP adress in `vpn.env`.

My problem seems to be that the execution of the 2nd systemd script is too "quick", and is completed before OpenVPN can start and write `vpn.env`.

**Question:** Is there some way to add a delay to the second script, perhaps a few seconds, and have it wait for the environment file to be written?

---

**systemd OpenVPN script**

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN Custom Launch Connection
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/vpn.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**OpenVPN .sh script, executed when program starts**

```
printenv > /etc/openvpn/vpn.env
```

**systemd Transmission script**

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon Under VPN
After=network.target vpn.service
Requires=vpn.service

[Service]
User=transmission
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/openvpn/vpn.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --config-dir /opt/transmission --bind-address-ipv4 $ifconfig_local --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 --no-portmap
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You could use a _timer_ with `OnBootSec=` directive ([example](http://jason.the-graham.com/2013/03/06/how-to-use-systemd-timers/))

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks, the link helped me. If you like, you can make an answer out of it. I tested the answer below but it had no bearing on my problem unfortunately.

Comment: Well, not really as it answers the question in your title not your actual problem. Anyways, after reading your question again I can see the reason for the answer below... See also this thread on [arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194792) maybe that helps and you can eventually manage to make them work as "start A only after B exits"

Comment: So OpenVPN writes that .env file as part of its "coming up process" then continues running in the background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is the `Type=simple` in the description of the VPN service.  The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Service_types) clarifies the [manual page](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=), a little:

> `Type=simple` (default): `systemd` considers the service to be started up immediately. The process must not fork. Do not use this type if other services need to be ordered on this service, unless it is socket activated.

You probably can make this work by changing the type:

> `Type=oneshot`: this is useful for scripts that do a single job and then exit. You **may** want to set `RemainAfterExit=yes` as well so that `systemd` still considers the service as active after the process has exited.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a delay: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43001223/32453

Or possibly could do this in your systemd OpenVPN service file:

```
 ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'do_bash_loop_that_waits_till_file_appears_here'
```

And another option: create a systemd [.path unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html). Maybe have it fire whenever that vpn.env file is created or changed.